# React - Array of Objects - Updating Object Property based on Input

Tags: reactjs, nested, state

I'm creating a workout log application, and I'm having an issue updating nested properties of state. This is my state...

```
this.state = {
     chosenExercises: [
                   {
                     id: 1, 
                     name: "Barbell Bench Press", 
                     type: "Strength", 
                     setCount: [1],
                     lbs: [], 
                     reps: []
                   },
                   {
                     id: 2,
                     name: "Dumbell Bench Press", 
                     type: "Strength", 
                     setCount: [1], 
                     lbs: [],
                     reps: []
                   }
                      ]
            } //End of state

//Function to update lbs from user input
     updateLbs = (lbs) => {
          //WHAT GOES HERE??
     }
```

The user input is 2 Components down, and it's part of a form that is in the parent component. Is it possible to update the lbs of each set for each exercise with a change handler in the parent component that gets passed down as props?

This is the outcome I'm looking for once that particular exercise is complete.

```
this.state = {
     chosenExercises: [
                   {
                     id: 1, 
                     name: "Barbell Bench Press", 
                     type: "Strength", 
                     setCount: [1, 2, 3, 4],
                     lbs: [135, 135, 155, 185], 
                     reps: [12, 12, 10, 8]
                   },
                   {
                     id: 2,
                     name: "Dumbell Bench Press", 
                     type: "Strength", 
                     setCount: [1], 
                     lbs: [],
                     reps: []
                   }
                      ]
            }
```

I've tried to work with .find() and .filter() together, but I'm simply not that good yet. I appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

just example how to update lbs functions. My idea is find a object which is need to be updated and update them, after that set state for chosenExercises by append others with an updated object.

```
//Function to update lbs from user input
    updateLbs = (lbs, id) => {
        //WHAT GOES HERE??

        let chosenExercise = this.state.chosenExercises.find(chosenExercise => chosenExercise['id'] === 1);

        if (chosenExercise === undefined)
            return;
        
        //update lbs
        chosenExercise['lbs'] = lbs;

        let remainChosenExercise = this.state.chosenExercises.filter(chosenExercise => chosenExercise['id'] !== 1);

        this.setState({chosenExercise: [...remainChosenExercise, chosenExercise]});
    }
```

Comment: This mostly would work. However, if the component at the end depends on the index location for rendering, the location of updated items will change to the end of the component list every time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some kind of identifier to know what you're updating. Whether it be the index location or the name (assuming the name is unique) or the id. In the example below, I'll assume you are passing the name of the exercise with the lbs update.

```js
update = (lbs, name) => {
  setState((prevState) => {
    const update = {...prevState};
    const index = update.chosenExcercises.findIndex((excercise) => excercise.name === name)
    update[index] = {
      ...update[index],
      lbs: [...update[index].lbs, lbs]
    }
    return {chosenExcercises: update}
  })
};
```

Comment: This throws an error stating Cannot read property findIndex of undefined. This project has become a nightmare because of this issue. I'm going to try and put everything in one component and update state the simple way. I really do appreciate the help!

Comment: Log `update` and see what the state is at the time of running the function.